# For any set $S_n=\{x \in \mathbb N \ |\ x \lt n \in \mathbb N \}$, there exists a bijection $f_n: S_n \to \{1,2,\cdots,n-1\}$

Tags: solution-verification, natural-numbers

I wanted to cross my t's and dot my i's regarding this below proof.

> For any set $S_n=\{x \in \mathbb N \ |\  x \lt n \in \mathbb N \}$, there exists a bijection $f_n: S_n \to \{1,2,\cdots,n-1\}$. Therefore, any such $S_n$ can be called **finite**.

To prove this, we can proceed with induction on $n$. I was a little concerned about my base case, given how I defined the codomain in the above theorem.

---

**Base Case**: $n=1$.

By definition, $S_0 = \emptyset$. Further, no such set of natural numbers satisfies the codomain requirements, so the codomain is also $\emptyset$. Let $f_0 = \emptyset$. Then we have the bijection $f_0: \emptyset \to \emptyset$.

**Assume for $n$**:

Suppose for any $n \gt 1$, there exists a bijection $f_n: S_n \rightarrow \{1,2,...,n-1\}$.

**Prove for $n+1$**:

Consider the set $S_{n+1}$. We have $n \in S_{n+1}$ because $n \lt n+1$ and $n \in \mathbb N$. $n$ must be the maximum of $S_{n+1}$ which means all other members of $S_{n+1}$ are less than $n$. But this just means $S_n \subset S_{n+1}$. Therefore, $S_{n+1}=S_n+\{n\}$. Let the bijective function $g$ be defined as $g: \{n\} \to \{n\}$. Now, let $f_{n+1}=f_n \cup g$ and note that $g \cap f_n = \emptyset$. The union of two non-intersecting bijective functions is, itself, a bijective function.

Comment: These sets are equal and it seems you're even assuming that by using $S_{n+1}=S_n\cup \{n\}$

Comment: @DavidP I know that the sets are equal, but I wanted to set the stage for variations of $S_n$, for example, $S_n = \{ x\in \mathbb N \ | \ m \lt x \lt n \in \mathbb\}$. So, really, I just wanted to make sure that the induction approach was valid and could be similarly deployed for different sets. Also, why would $S_{n+1}=S_n \cup \{n\}$ imply that the domain and codomain are equal?

Comment: $S_2=S_1\cup\{1\} = \emptyset\cup \{1\}=\{1\}, S_3=S_2\cup\{2\} = \{1\}\cup \{2\}=\{1,2\}$ etc

Comment: @DavidP Isn't the induction approach just formalizing your above argument?

Comment: My point was, how do you know that $S_{n+1}=S_n\cup \{n\}$ at all? If you knew that the proof does not require anything about functions.

Comment: @DavidP I wanted to apply the formal definition of finiteness, which is why I talked about bijective functions. Do you recommend a different approach? (I see that the bijective function, in this particular case, is the identity function restricted to the relevant $S_n$ domain).